# Unable to remove PHP old path from system

Tags: mojave, php, mamp

Ever since I updated my MacBook PRO from 8.0 8.2, I can't seem to symlink php or add php to path anymore. I have to give the full path.

```
$ php -v
-bash: /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php8.0.8/bin/php: No such file or directory
```

```
$ /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php8.2.0/bin/php -v
PHP 8.2.0 (cli) (built: Dec  9 2022 09:00:24) (NTS)
Copyright (c) The PHP Group
Zend Engine v4.2.0, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies
```

```
$ sudo mv /usr/bin/php /usr/bin/~php
mv: rename /usr/bin/php to /usr/bin/~php: Operation not permitted
$ sudo ln -s /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php8.2.0/bin/php /usr/bin/php
ln: /usr/bin/php: Operation not permitted
```

```
$ export PATH=$PATH:/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php8.2.0/bin
$ php -v
-bash: /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php8.0.8/bin/php: No such file or directory
$ echo $PATH
blah-blah-blah:/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php8.0.8/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php8.2.0/bin:blah-blah-blah:
```

```
php -v
-bash: /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php8.0.8/bin/php: No such file or directory
```

Where is php8.0.8 stoned in ? Which file do I search for ?

macOS Mojave.

Comment: WHat does `which php` show? Note that the shell will find the php that is in the directory FIRST on the PATH so the blah-blah-blah is what matters not the MAMP bit.

Comment: The usual : `/usr/bin/php`

Comment: I have no /usr/bin/php (Ventura). What is the contents of php? Is it binary or a script?

Comment: `head -n 5 /usr/bin/php` returns starts with `???__PAGEZERO(__TEXT????__text__TEXTAiE?__stubs__TEXT^~E?^~?__stub_helper__TEXT$?E?1$?E?__cons`